# How to get the uploaded image from localhost database(mysql) to android?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am just new to uploading and retrieving images from localhost databases to android. How can I do this ? I've tried to think of it for three(3) days and I don't know how to code it. Here's the thing:

1. How to Save an image from, android emulator --> localhost database ?
2. How to Get the image from, localhost database --> android emulator ? So that whenever I open my android app it shows the image (just 1 image) that I uploaded ..

Comment: You need to set uses-permission - android.permission.INTERNET in AndroidManifest.xml and then first find out your router external IP address, then forward some port to that 10.0.2.2:portno and finally you'll be able to see that server from your device.

Comment: Try making an uploader in php, and read about multipart form uploading in android. Do not store the image directly to the database as it is not recommended most of the time, they just transfer the image to a directory (the php uploader) and saves the url of the directory in the database so its just a varchar, so whenever they need to retrieve the image they just call the directory in android / webpages / etc.

Comment: @HimanshuAgarwal Thanks, but I already set that permission. I've done some things, like registration and updating data. But the main problem is how to Save an image and how to Get the image data.

Comment: @Mike, uploader in php? how's that sir? Can you give me some code so that I can have a guide. Thanks

Comment: Hmm I cannot code right now since im outside, but its not really an uploader it just moves the file or image in a directory and saves its directory + image name (folder/img.png) in the database for retrieval. If im right its something like move_uploaded_file() in php.

Comment: @MaxMaximo you can use Base64 encoding to convert image into string and vise versa to get image from string.

Comment: @Mike, i get the logic but I'm a little bit confused on how to code it.

Comment: @HimanshuAgarwal, can I have some code of yours as a guide? Thanks

Comment: You need to get a read about RESTful service if you are not familiar with it. Basically there would be networking calls in your android app and you will have the php service to catch the networking calls.

Comment: @Mike, thanks, but if you have a time to give me some of your codes I think it would be easier for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

First before uploading change your image to byteArray

```
 ByteArrayOutputstream bos;
 Bitmap bm ;
 byte[] bitmapdata,bb;
 bm= BitmapFactory.decodeResourses(getResources() ,R.drawable.image);
 bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 String convert_txt;
```

When image store in byte fromat in your database then try to get Image from database

```
 bitmapdata = bos.tobyteArray();
 for(int i =0 i<bitmapdata.length ; i++){
  convert_txt = convert_txt+bitmapdata[i];
  }
  Cursor cursor = dh.rawQuery("Select statement....");
 bb = cursor.getblob(cursor.getColumnIndex("columnanme"));
```

Comment: I have a problem regarding to your codes. I'm just new in uploading and getting the image from database. Please, explain each code. Thanks

Comment: Your image will be uploaded on server database by client or server.??

Comment: Uploaded from Android emulator and then store it from localhost database.

Comment: I'm going to try this. Thanks

Comment: Does it work for you..? If yes let me know and if no , let me know,,

Comment: I'm still doing it. I have some problem, what if I already have an image inside my database. How can i get the image and display it on my android emulator?

Comment: hmm, JPEG and PNG only.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example to encode and decode an Image into `Base64`

Simple function that you need pass bitmap and it will return a string:

```
/**
   * @param bitmap
   * @return converting bitmap and return a string
*/
public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
        byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
        String temp=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return temp;
  }
```

Here is the reverse procedure for converting string to bitmap but string should Base64 encoding

```
  /**
   * @param encodedString
   * @return bitmap (from given string)
   */
public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString){
  try{
    byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(encodedString,Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
    return bitmap;
   }catch(Exception e){
     e.getMessage();
     return null;
   }
}
```

So now you can save encoded Image String to your database as you already done for other variable as well to decode String to Bitmap

Comment: I'll try your code and later I will post or just comment the result. Thanks

Comment: Wait, does this codes works through android to localhost database, vice versa?

Comment: yes it will as you said earlier you already done registration and sending data to locolhost so through this you can save image in String format.

Comment: what if I already have an image in the database before. How can I get the image and show it on my android emulator?

Comment: if you have url of that image you can use `Universal Image Loader` that provide better image loading and memory management.

Answer (score 0):

I have my code here, since it was about Profile Image and also I am using the android emulator wherein I have images from the SDCARD and it was successfully changed but it doesn't save from the database. I will just some of my codes.

```
imageProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectImageFromGallery();

        }
    });


public void selectImageFromGallery() {
     Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.setType("image/*");
     intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
     startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

 if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

     Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
     String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

     Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
      filePathColumn, null, null, null);
      cursor.moveToFirst();

      int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
      String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
      cursor.close();
      Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), picturePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      decodeFile(picturePath);

 }
}

public void decodeFile(String filePath) {

    // Decode image size
     BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
     o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

     // The new size we want to scale to
     final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 270;

     // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
     int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
     int scale = 1;
     while (true) {
      if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
              break;
      width_tmp /= 2;
      height_tmp /= 2;
      scale *= 2;
     }

     // Decode with inSampleSize
     BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
     o2.inSampleSize = scale;
     bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);

     imageProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

Comment: I try to put your codes inside my code, but I don't know how .. Anyway, I can upload and I don't know how to save it from the database.

Comment: I have a screenshot here but i cannot post it here because it requires for 10 reputation. -.-